# xdotool creating weird characters and adding some characters in prompt

Tags: shell-script, command-line, x11, gnome3, xdotool

I am using Zorin OS, based on Gnome.

I am using xdotool version 3.20160805.1

I am using zsh with alacritty. However, the following issues can be seen in bash and gnome terminal in different form (it does print nothing but also does nothing).

In my machine `alt+F10`'s ascii value is `^[[21;3~%`. `alt+F10` is to toggle maximization state of a window. I am trying to toggle maximization state of a given window.

However, the command xdotool creating weird characters and adding some characters in prompt.

```
$ xdotool type asdfasdfasdf
asdf
$ asdfasdfasdf

$ xdotool key --window $(xdotool getactivewindow) "alt+F10"
^[[21;3~%
$ ;3~

$ xdotool getactivewindow key "alt+F10"
^[[21;3~%
$ ;3~
```

in the above command examples, `$` represent a new prompt.

If I create shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash

WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
xdotool key --window $WINDOW_ID "alt+F10" # alt+F10 is ^[[21;3~
xdotool getwindowgeometry $WINDOW_ID
```

then the output is like:

```
$ ./width
^[[21;3~Window 69206020
  Position: 1330,447 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 800x600
$ ;3~
```

So, it is not maximizing the window then getting the dimension?

What can I do?

Comment: Does it work if in the activewindow you run something like `cat > /dev/tty` ?